# Career averages for players that have played in current season

Tags: mysql, having-clause

I am trying to list the player averages over their careers but only including players that have played at least one game in 2018, but my query is just returning players that have played 'only' in 2018, rather than the career averages for all players that have played at least one game in 2018.

```
SELECT PlayerID
     , Surname
     , AKA
     , COUNT(*) AS Played
     , ROUND(AVG(Kicks),1) AS K
     , ROUND(AVG(Handballs),1) AS HB
     , ROUND(AVG(Marks),1) AS M
     , Season
  FROM `PlayerDetails` 
 WHERE Team = 'Team A'
 GROUP 
    BY PlayerID 
HAVING Season = 2018
 ORDER 
    BY Surname ASC
```

Comment: what your table and data looks like? sqlfiddle can help so we can understand your problem

Comment: Having max(season) = 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove your `HAVING` clause and add to your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT PlayerID, Surname,AKA, COUNT(*) AS Played, ROUND(AVG(Kicks),1) AS K, ROUND(AVG(Handballs),1) AS HB, ROUND(AVG(Marks),1) AS M, Season
FROM `PlayerDetails` p1
WHERE Team = 'Team A'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `PlayerDetails` p2 WHERE p2.playerID = p1.playerID AND Season = 2018)
GROUP BY PlayerID 
ORDER BY Surname ASC
```

The `HAVING` clause that you had - as you found - restricted the query only to results from 2018. The `EXISTS` clause I have added to the `WHERE` will find any player who has played in 2018.

Comment: In this instance, because we know that the max season is 2018, we might be able to dream up a simpler solution

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, that would work for this query. Mine is a more general solution. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: I've gone with Nick's solution  - works perfect - I was able to expand on it to also include career averages against opponents to.  Thanks